# Como posso encontrar o último dia do mês em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Por exemplo, se eu tenho a data 04/04, como obtenho o último dia de abril (neste caso seria 30)? Tem algo pronto ou tem que "calcular"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem pronto, mas não com esta função. E entenda que precisa saber o ano para encontrar a quantidade exata. Se não for fevereiro pode até usar qualquer ano, mas se quiser algo exato precisa saber o ano para definir se terá 28 ou 29 dias. E não é tão simples saber quanto algumas pessoas pensam. O dia não importa.

O .NET tem um método que diz quantos dias tem um mês, que é o mesmo que o último dia:

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(2023, 04);
DateTime.DaysInMonth(2020, 02);
DateTime.DaysInMonth(2023, 02);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3FyYQV). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Auxaw9). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/LastDayMonth.cs).